# jQuery $.post not returning JSON data

Tags: php, json, jquery

I've read multiple similar posts on this, and my code seems to match the suggestions, but still no data returned.

Here's my JS:

```
    $.post('php/get_last_word.php', { user_id : userID },
        function( data ) {
            currentLanguage = data.language_id;
            currentWord = data.word_id;
            console.log("currentLanguage = " + currentLanguage)
            console.log("currentWord = " + currentWord);        
    },'json');
```

And the relevant php:

```
$user_id=$_POST['user_id'];

mysql_select_db(wordsicle_search); 

$sql = "SELECT `language_id`, `word_id` FROM `save_state` WHERE `user_id`=$user_id";
$result = mysql_query($sql,$con);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $encoded = json_encode($row);
    echo $encoded;
}
```

And the resulting log:

```
Connected successfully{"language_id":"1","word_id":"1"}
```

So the json array is being echoed, but it's not ending up in `data`, because `currentLanguage` and `currentWord` are not being populated. Is this a problem with asynchronicity? Or something else?

Comment: Why is it in a `while` loop? Are you expecting more than one result? If so, that's your problem; otherwise, just make it an `if`. Then there's the fact that they're called `language_id` and `word_id`, not `language` and `word`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have a valid json coming back to your variable from your PHP script

IF your json object is like this,

```
{"language_id":"1","word_id":"1"}
```

You can access the values like this

```
currentLanguage = data.language_id;
currentWord = data.word_id;
```

Example JsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/NuS7Z/8/

You can use http://jsonlint.com/ to verify your jSon is in correct form or not.

Specifying `json` as the data type value in your post request will make sure the reponse is coming back as `json` format to the success callback.

```
$.post('php/get_last_word.php',{user_id:userID}, dataType:"json",function(data){
        currentLanguage = data.language_id;
        currentWord = data.word_id;
});
```

You can also use `getJson` to simply get json data. getJson is a shorthand of ajax Call with datatype as json

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: Thanks, I missed that. However, it still isn't returning anything with that fixed.

Comment: @SmoothAlmonds: See my updated answer with an example link. I guess your jSon is not valid. You dont need that "Completed Successfully" in your jSon.

Comment: Fixed. It was a stupid error. I had an "echo 'Connected successfully';" statement in the php file after connecting, and before returning data, so that was being returned first. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your JS to:

```
 $.getJSON('php/get_last_word.php', { user_id : userID },
        function( response ) {
            if (response.success) {
                currentLanguage = response.data.language_id;
                currentWord = response.data.word_id;
                console.log("currentLanguage = " + currentLanguage)
                console.log("currentWord = " + currentWord);     
            } else {
                alert('Fail');
            }   
    });
```

and your PHP to:

```
<?php
$success = false;
$data = null;
$user_id=$_POST['user_id'];

mysql_select_db(wordsicle_search); 

$sql = "SELECT `language_id`, `word_id` FROM `save_state` WHERE `user_id`=$user_id";
$result = mysql_query($sql,$con);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $success = true;
    $data = $row;
}

// I generally format my JSON output array like so:

// Response
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array(
    'success' => $success,
    'data' => $data
));

?>
```

That way its more organized and don't forget to set the content type.

Hope that helps.